# Stretching a view to span the parent's height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with three views:

```
|--------|
| View 1 |
|--------|
| View 2 |
|--------|
| View 3 |
|--------|
|        |
|--------|
```

I would like View 3 to be at the below of the screen and View 2 to span the available space:

```
|--------|
| View 1 |
|--------|
|        |
| View 2 |
|        |
|--------|
| View 3 |
|--------|
```

Is there some way of achieving this that works on all screen types on Android?

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify what your asking. Can you review it to make sure I haven't misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

In xml use Relativelayout selectproperty of view1 as alignparenttop & view2 as centerinparent & view3 as alignparentbottom after that give weights to the views and adjust it as you wish to do

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple solution would be using a vertical LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="48dp" />

    <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="48dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

By using `layout_weight`, you can allow a view to consume a portion of the LinearLayout. Since the parent layout consumes the dimensions of its parent, the middle view stretches to fill the space between the top and bottom.